# Access Data Source Fields from Report code behind

Tags: telerik, telerik-reporting

I want to programmatically access the `Fields` collection in the `ObjectDataSource` object of my Telerik report.

I did notice in the design portion of the Telerik report you can access the fields collection
in the Value by using the Edit Expression window.

Example:

```
= Fields.MyFieldName
```

How would I accomplish this task using C# code in the report code behind file?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. This is how I solved it, although I believe there should be an easier way.

First I created a method for the details section itemdatabinding:

```
private void detail_ItemDataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Telerik.Reporting.Processing.DetailSection section = (sender as Telerik.Reporting.Processing.DetailSection);
        object id = section.DataObject["Data Field You want to access"];
        Variable Name = id.ToString();
    }
```

You can now use that variable anywhere in your codebehind.
Note: The Data Field must appear in your detail section. In my case I did not need it to show, so I just made 'Visible=false'.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Bind Data to your own data to your variables

```
string ItemCode = "a";
 string ItemDesc = "aa"
```

Then bind it to the data source

```
var Output = new
            {              
                ItemCode = a.ItemCode,
                ItemDesc = a.ItemDesc,                    
            };

            this.DataSource = Output;
```

All these are in code behind. Then move to design portion and modify your text-box as shown below.

```
= Fields.ItemCode 
= Fields.ItemDesc
```